# F# recursive function alternating between plus and minus

Tags: recursion, f#, evaluation

I'm asked to remove one clause in below F# function, while maintaining it's functionality, that's alternating between plus and minus.

```
let rec altsum =
    function
    | [] -> 0
    | [ x ] -> x
    | x0 :: x1 :: xr -> x0 - x1 + altsum xr
```

I stumbled upon below solution, but I don't quite understand how it evaluates to the correct result since it only contain a minus symbol and not a plus symbol. Can someone please explain how below function `altsum1` evaluates?

```
let rec altsum1 =
    function
    | [] -> 0
    | x0 :: xr -> x0 - altsum1 xr
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works because `-1 * -1 = 1`. We can then use the distributive property to show that:

```
a - (b - c) = a - b + c
```

So:

```
altsum([1; 2; 3; 4]) =
1 - altsum([2; 3; 4]) =
1 - (2 - altsum([3; 4])) =
1 - (2 - (3 - altsum[4])) =
1 - (2 - (3 - 4)) =
1 - 2 + 3 - 4 =
-2
```